# Android nested spinners throwing BadTokenException

Tags: android, exception, nested, spinner

I am trying to make a "custom component" (not yet what android means by custom component, just trying to put together different components) that nests 2 spinners. The approach is this: the first spinner has row items, and a row has a textview and another spinner. My problem is this: I can view the nested spinners and by debugging it I know they both have the correct values, but when I try to click on the nested spinner I get this exception:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@5277d51c is not valid; is your activity running?
```

The layout file for a row for the top-level spinner is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/linearLayoutContainer"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:paddingLeft="0dp"
              android:paddingRight="0dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinnerItemText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/innerSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ></Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am using Android Studio 0.8.9, gradle 1.12, Android API 20,.

If you need any other information please let me know.